# how to navigate html pages without loading using htmx

Tags: htmx

I want to load an html page without refreshing the page using htmx. So for example, If I am at http://localhost/sample/home and I want to navigate to contact us page, I click on the contact link and the contact page content gets loaded without refreshing the page.
Is it possible?

Comment: We'd like to see what you've tried to solve this. It's much easier, and more helpful, if you provide a snippet showing your attempt, and provide an explanation of why it didn't work, than for us to write a tutorial explaining how to do something. That's the Stack Overflow way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible with htmx.  Take a look at the [hx-get](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-get/) tag as an example.

```html
<html>
<body hx-target="this">
<a hx-get="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>.  When this link is clicked, the document body will be swapped with whatever you have in the file named /contact-us
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about `hx-boost`.

> The hx-boost attribute allows you to "boost" normal anchors and form tags to use AJAX instead.

It reminds me of the `react-router` approach.

https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-boost/